# Angular Material 5: how to call a function when a tab is selected (clicked)?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material-5

I have the following html code

```
<mat-tab label="Regular" (selectChange)="tabClick()"
                 (click)="tabClick()">
   <h1>Some more tab content</h1>
</mat-tab>
```

and this is the function,

```
tabClick(){
    console.log('Tab clicked...');
}
```

but it doesn't seems to be called, why? No one of the above events are fired?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `selectedTabChanged` event has to be attached to the `<mat-tab-group>` element

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabClick($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

---

```
tabClick(tab) {
  console.log(tab);
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2pgt1)

Comment: ok, then how to detect which tab was selected, e.g. passing the tab label to tabClick('selectedLabel') ?

Comment: You have to pass the `$event` object, see updated answer

Comment: In my eyes, the answer is almost, but not entirely correct. The `click` event usually is triggered before the tab is changed. `selectChange` is triggered after the tab has changed. You can use it to prevent the tab change, nor can you use it to clear the resources of components while they are visible. (Granted, the latter is an unusual use-case, but it's the use-case I'm currently fighting with).

Comment: still, both tabs are triggering the method.  How can we do it that only one of the tab will trigger the method?

Answer (score 9):

An event should be `selectedTabChange` to the `mat-tab-group`

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabClick()">
    <mat-tab label="Regular">
       <h1>Some more tab content</h1>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: @bugs Yup, I forgot to change Element name , Answer Updated

Answer (score 4):

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onChange($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Selected tab will trigger out the tabChange Event and get the active tab.

And in the `.ts` file:

```
onChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    const tab = event.tab.textLabel;
    console.log(tab);
    if(tab===" Tab 1")
     {
       console.log("function want to implement");
      }
  }
```

Comment: this is more type safe and should be answer

Answer (score 0):

SelectTab is used to call click-on tab data.

```
 <tab (selectTab) = "onChange($event)" >
        <div>
            any data
        </div>
    </tab >
    

    onChange(data:any){
    console.log(data)
    }
```